# textbf+UpperCase title

Tags: fonts, macros, sectioning, formatting

I would like to make a section title UpperCase+textbf, however, while trying to define it like this

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{
    \@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}%
    {\baselineskip} 
    {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\textbf\MakeUppercase}      
   }%
   \makeatother
```

an error is produced.

If I use only one of these two properties (`\textbf` or `\MakeUppercase`), everything works fine, so what's the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 8):

`\textbf` takes an argument (and so just gets `\MakeUppercase` as its argument here). Use the declaration form, `\bfseries` instead.